# Can't delete azure database

Tags: azure

In the sql server database list here:

```
https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/SqlAzureExtension/Databases
```

I select a database and at the bottom is "Delete".

I press delete and it processes a little while then says:

> Could not delete database 'system-50e5f905-...etc'

I follow a link for more details where it just says:

> Bad Request

**Extra info**

They do not appear to be linked resources anywhere.

I have been able to create and delete a new database.

I have also connected using MS SQL server management studio and I can only see two named databases, none of the databases that have a name format of `system-guid` for a name.

Comment: Is it registered as `linked resource` somewhere?

Comment: @weston: sorry, my comment came out wrong. My point is that only Azure support can look into the issue. First is the 'could not delete' issue, which sounds like a backend or gateway problem. And then there is a bad link/request on the portal, really nothing we can do about it here...

Comment: @RemusRusanu It's a fair point actually and I did try to go their support first, but all I can get with my current subscription is billing support. Maybe as I'm paying for these unwanted databases it comes under billing support, it's a long shot!

Comment: @weston - Please note that Azure is a Stack Overflow sponsor (thus the little icon in the question tag) but that isn't really related to or a prerequisite for directing tech support here. Azure questions are welcome as soon as they follow the site guidelines, but Stack Overflow is not an official or unofficial support site for any specific third-party project.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I looked into this, I think this Q follows the guidelines for SO as a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: @weston - I never questioned that. I only stated that Stack Overflow is not affiliated to Microsoft or Azure.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Noted, but all I said was "Azure recommend this site for community support" which is a fact.

Comment: @weston - An irrelevant fact, actually ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases with the name format `system-SOME GUID` may be federations.

Deletion (Dropping) of a federation must be done within the database Management Portal for the main database.

**Caution:** I don't know the ramifications of dropping a federation, so make sure you have backups of data you don't want to lose or research this further.

1. From https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/SqlAzureExtension/Databases
2. Select the main database
3. Select "Design your SQL database"
4. Log on
5. At the top you see "server > [DB] > Tables", Click [DB]
6. Federations are shown on this page and you can select them and "Drop Federation"

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my database on Azure using "SQL Server Management Studio" , right click Delete.

using Code First with Update-Database command, it will re Created.